# Creating a folder in a pure QML application

Tags: directory, qml

I've an application which is pure QML (no backend). And I'd like to create a folder.

Is this possible ?
I found old answers saying that it wasn't.

I wonder if with newer versions of QML it would be possible. I couldn't find any information on this.

I'm using **QtQuick 2.9**

---

[EDIT]

Context:

This application is actually a **plugin** for the [Musical score editor MuseScore](https://musescore.org/fr). The plugins are written in QML and have access to the underlying application through [a limited number of MuseScore objects and methods](https://musescore.org/en/handbook/developers-handbook/plugins-3x). Sufficient to do most tasks a plugin should do.

The plugin I'm working on is an *export* plugin, that exports PDF, JPG, ... versions of the scores. What I'm trying to achieve is to create a folder structure in the export folder that will depend on the score properties. E.g. If there is a score from John Coltrane, create a subfolder "John Coltrane" and exports all the scores by John Coltrane in that folder.

The creation/writing of the files is supported by 2 MuseScore objects ([1](https://musescore.github.io/MuseScore_PluginAPI_Docs/plugins/html/class_ms_1_1_plugin_a_p_i_1_1_plugin_a_p_i.html#afa262b02973fcb0ca17c0cbdaa29af9a), [2](https://musescore.github.io/MuseScore_PluginAPI_Docs/plugins/html/class_ms_1_1_plugin_a_p_i_1_1_file_i_o.html) ) but none of them supports **non existing folders**.

This is where my question arrives. How can I create the folders from the QML plugin itself ?

An option is definitely to raise a Change Request to the MuseScore team so that 2 above-mentioned objects supports non-existing folders, but it wouldn't be implemented before min 6 months. I'm a little more impatient...

This is my plugin declaration:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2 // FileDialogs
import QtQuick.Window 2.3
import Qt.labs.folderlistmodel 2.2
import Qt.labs.settings 1.0
import QtQml 2.8
import MuseScore 3.0
import FileIO 3.0
import "batch_convert"

MuseScore {
    menuPath: "Plugins." + qsTr("Batch Convert") // this doesn't work, why?
    version: "3.6"
    requiresScore: false
    description: qsTr("This plugin converts multiple files from various formats"
                      + " into various formats")
    pluginType: "dialog"
```

Comment: In pure QML you cannot access the local FS, I guess due to the security reason. You have to extend your application by some C++ extension to do that.

Comment: Alas, this is not possible in my case (qml is the language for writing plugin, like VBA for excel)

Comment: ok, then this is a systemic flaw of such a system. as a workaround you can use some external system that you can communicate with using some protocol WebSocket for example.

Comment: @lvr123 could you give us more information on your challenge? What should your plugin achieve? Maybe there is a different solution for your problem

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan: done. I added a context in the original question.

Comment: @lvr123 please check your [edit] again, it does not show up for me

Comment: Now it does show up.

Comment: I see that this project is [open source](https://github.com/musescore/MuseScore). You just can add the missed functionality and so send a pull request to the developer. Unfortunately, the developers are not in a hurry, judging by the number of opened issues (495) and pull requests (148)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `QProcess` and a platform-specific script :

```
QProcess {
    id: proc
}

function mkdir(qproc, path) {
    var cmd;
    
    // Platform-based command
    switch (Qt.platform.os) {
    case "windows":
        cmd = "cmd /c mkdir \"" + path + "\"";
        break;
    default:
        cmd = "/bin/sh -c \"mkdir -p '"+path+"'\"";
    }
    
    // Execution
    var res = false;
    qproc.start(cmd);
    res = qproc.waitForFinished(3000);
    console.log("-- STDOUT : " + qproc.readAllStandardOutput());
    //console.log("-- STDERR :  " + qproc.readAllStandardError());

    // !! "true" doesn't mean it all went right. E.g. calling "cmd /c foobar" will return true even if the foobar" command does not exist !!
    return (res ? true : false);
}

mkdir(proc,"/path/to/a/new/folder");
```

---

Remark: the QML `QProcess` object as used in that solution is the way Musescore (my development context) exposes the C++ `QProcess` class to QML, it might be different in other contexts.